# Finding changed records in a database table

Tags: sql, database

I have a problem that I haven't been able to come up with a solution for yet. I have a database (actually thousands of them at customer sites) that I want to extract data from periodically. I'd like to do a full data extract one time (select * from table) then after that only get rows that have changed.

The challenge is that there aren't any updated date columns in most of the tables that could be used to constrain the SQL query. I can't use a trigger based approach nor change the application that writes to the database since it's another group that develops the app and they are way backed up already.

I may be able to write to the database tables when doing the data extract, but would prefer not to do that. Does anyone have any ideas for how we might be able to do this?

Comment: Go add in auto-increment id rows to every table in every database (really).

Comment: Yeah I'm assuming if this is MySQL, there most likely will be auto-incremented id columns for nearly all the tables. If so, I guess you could write a script or manually mark down what id's you left off at.

Comment: does your flavor of sql support command line query?

Comment: As mentioned below I think an auto-increment column will only get me any newly inserted rows. It won't help to know which rows have changed since the last time I queried.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to programatically mark the records.  I see suggestions of an auto-incrementing field but that will only get newly inserted records.  How will you track updated or deleted records?

If you only want newly inserted that an autoincrementing field will do the job; in subsequent data dumps grab every thing since the last value of the autoincrment field and then recrod the current value.

If you want updates the minimum I can see is to have a last_update field and probably a trigger to populare it.  If the last_update is later the the last data dump grab that record.  This will get inserts and updates but not deletes.

You could try something like a 'instead of delete' trigger if your RDBMS supports it and NULL the last_update field.  On subsequent data dumps grap all recoirds where this field is NULL and then delete them.  But there would be problems with this (e.g. how to stop the app seeing them between the logical and physical delete)

The most fool proof method I can see is aset of  history (audit) tables and ech change gets written to them.  Then you select your data dump from there.

By the way do you only care about know the updates have happened?  What about if 2 (or more) updates have happened.  The history table is the only way that I can see you capturing this scenario.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not going to be able to add triggers to this database and writing to the database at all will be sketchy. I only care if a row has changed since the last time I queried it. It doesn't matter how many times it changed or what the in-between changes were.

Comment: If you are that constrained I would consider grabbing a full copy each time and doing the comparison at your end.  Then you'll find both updates and deletes as well.

Comment: Thanks, Karl. That's what we are currently doing (more accurately in the process of developing). What I was hoping was that someone had an idea we hadn't thought of for making it work closer to the database itself so we didn't have to transfer the entire thing every time.

Answer (score 0):

This should isolate rows that have changed since your last backup. Assuming DestinationTable is a copy of SourceTable even on the key fields; if not you could list out the important fields.

```
 SELECT * FROM SourceTable
 EXCEPT
 SELECT * FROM DestinationTable
```